# heatmap-like legend for geom_segment above a geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

In my plot below, a waveform has a colored line above it that signals statistical significance for each time point (grey: not significant, shades of blue: significant, with darker blue being more negative t-scores).

Dataframe `data`:

```
data <- structure(list(x = -10:10, y = c(1.17212311444692, 0.0796231128715192, 
    0.0884179665923377, 0.528897391178863, -0.943528827648172, 0.0677093946037336, 
    -0.553815297396959, -2.09355889431236, -1.4073660716519, 2.15345031622522, 
    1.32470201744841, 1.7682989226011, -0.36884335521017, -1.02874953756008, 
    0.706049415549804, -0.622101718842982, -0.670885289277569, 0.178799361542821, 
    -0.0387849590281491, -2.11303096472901, -1.76748424511596)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -21L))
```

plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_segment(aes(x=-10, xend=3, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="grey", size=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=3, xend=6, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="dodgerblue2", size=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=6, xend=7.5, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="blue2", size=2) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=7.5, xend=8, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="blue4", size=2) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=8, xend=9, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="blue2", size=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=9, xend=10, y=4.5, yend=4.5), color="grey", size=2)
```

[image]

What I need to do is to also have a heatmap-like legend for the colors. Does someone have any idea of how to do it? All the solutions I found refer to the `geom_tile` command but I can't figure out how to make it suit my plotting needs.

Comment: did anyone think about a solution? i know it's tricky...

Comment: What you are asking for can be achieved with `scale_fill_manual()`, though it *would* be better if the significance level can be determined from your dataset itself, rather than hard-coded into geom segments.